# Why is my React ref not mounting in map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using this line to create refs using ref callback

```
    setRef = (ref) => {
        this.inputRefs.push(ref);
      };
```

Here I is my render function where the refs are added

```
render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={(e) => { this.removePopUpBox(e) }}>
                <div> {this.state.popUpBox ? <PopUpBox /> : null} </div>
                <div className="add" onClick={this.addPopUpBox}>+</div>
                <div className="tasks-wrap">
                    {this.state.items.map((task, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Item ref={this.setRef} index={index} key={index} item={task} remove={this.remove}/>
                    )})}
                </div>


            </div>);
    }
```

And this is my constructor

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.inputRefs = []
}
```

For some reason my refs are initialized but are not being mounted to the elements so any call to current is returning as undefined.
Thank you!

Comment: The way you have this set up is using callback refs so I'm pretty sure you wouldn't access them using the `current` accessor.  Check the docs on those here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs

Comment: First option, will creating 1 ref for (`<div className="tasks-wrap">`) and accessing items as it's children (`ref.childNodes`) help solve the issue?

Comment: Second option, maybe try using [`React.createRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref) API to generate refs for each element in `this.state.items`.

Comment: BTW with functional callback (as in code above) there is not need to call `.current`, each element is just a DOM element. See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs)